# c++ program to check entered number by user

Tags: c++

I am new to programming, started with C++ quite recently and I use CLion IDE.

I need to solve something, but I am not sure how exactly and I need your help with a basic C++ console program.

if the user enters a ten-digit number and the fifth number is one, the output should be this word - "zadochno".

if the user enters a ten-digit number and the fifth number is two, the output should be this word - "redovno".

The user is expected to enter 2101**1**62235 or similar.
In any case, the fifth element should be either 1 or 2.

Examples:

Option 1: input> 2101**1**62235 -> output string "zadochno"

Option 2: input> 2101**2**62235 -> output string "redovno"

I am able to only partially create the program:

```cpp
#include<iostream>

int number;
cout << "Please, enter number: ";
cin > number;

//I believe there should be an if statement or for loop here:
if(){

}
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: is the user input always a 10 digit number? or can it be anything and yuo need to check if it is a 10 digit number?

Comment: Note that `int` typically cannot express all 10-digit numbers because it is usually a 32-bit number.

Comment: Yes, the user input always a 10 digit number.

Comment: If the input is always a 10 digit number, I think you could read a string instead of int, e.g. `string number;` and than `cin > number`, and than you could just check `if (number[4] == '1') {}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the input from the user as `std::string` and then check if the element at index `4` is `1` or `2` as shown below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    std::string input;
    
    //take input from user 
    std::getline(std::cin, input);
    
    //check if the 5th letter(at index 4 since indexing starts with 0) is '1' or '2'
    if(input.at(4) == '1')
    {
        std::cout<< "zadochno"<<std::endl;
    }
    else if(input.at(4) == '2')
    {
        std::cout << "redovno"<<std::endl;
    }
    
    //this below shown for loop is optional. If you're sure that the user input contains only digits then you can skip/remove this for loop.
    for(int i = 0; i < input.size(); ++i)
    {
        //check if the all the characters are digits of a number 
        if(std::isdigit(input[i]))
        {
            ;//std::cout<<"yes digit";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout<<"Please enter a valid number"<<std::endl;
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above program can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/hlQlZsENq).

Comment: **Caution!** You don't check the `std::string` length. Although `at()` does that and throw exceptions if you are out-of-bounds (unlike `operator[]()`!). I strongly recommend you to check that yourself and print a helpful error message to the user.

Comment: @DevilishSpirits I was thinking of adding a check for string length but then i read OP's comment that the input is always a 10 digit number. So there is no need for checking the length. Also, as you said, to make sure that we don't go out of bound i have used `at`. If the user(OP) wants to check the length then he/she can add it. It's **trivial**.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the user does enter a 10 digit number (ie you don't need to check if they enter eg `"foo"` or `"bar3000"`), you can do the following:

Read the input as a `std::string`, not as `int`. User input is a string of characters always. Only if you need it you can get it converted to an integer. You do not need it as `int`. The n-th character of a `std::string` called `user_input` is `user_input[n]`. You just need to check whether the character in the middle is either `'1'` or `'2'`.

If you do need to check that the user did enter digits, you could use `std::isdigit`.